# Basis for subset of $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a subset of $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all functions of the form

$$a\sin(x+c) + b\cos(x+d)$$

Where $a,b,c,d$ are constants and $x$ is a variable. Prove that $W$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace, and find the basis.

I understand how to prove the W is a subspace, but I'm not sure how to find a basis. I'm confused as to how you would represent a basis for a function, and also how you could create a basis that allows you to "access" the c or d constants for lack of a better word.

Comment: $\sin(x+c)=\sin(x)\cos(c)+\cos(x)\sin(c)$ is a linear combination of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Comment: Right. I used that identity in my proof of W as a subspace, but I'm still not sure how to come up with a basis for W.

Comment: are $a,b,c$ and $d$ fixed? And are you considering $W$ as a real vector space, or are you using some other field?

Comment: I don't think a,b,c,d are fixed, as it is supposed to be all functions of the form. And yes, W is a real vector space.

Comment: then a basis is $\sin x,\cos x$, since a function $f(x)=a\sin(x+c)+b\cos(x+d)$ is equal to $(a\cos c-b\sin c)\sin x+(a\sin c+b\cos c)\cos x$, so $f$ is a linear combination of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. You just need to prove that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are independent

Comment: That clears things up. Thanks!